# Efficient Retrieve of MongoDB items in a time range

Tags: mongodb

I am having a MongoDb collection of 70M items (200GB) and I am trying to get those in the range [`from_date`, `to_date`] using the command:

```
from_date = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 14, 9, 46, 23)
to_date = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 14, 9, 46, 24)
db.collection.find({"datetime": {"$gte": from_date, "$lte": to_date}})
```

However it takes a lot of time to retrieve those items even for a single query. Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do you have an index on `datetime` field ?

Comment: When I was creating the collection I applied `db.collection.create_index([('id', pymongo.ASCENDING)], unique=True)`. Should I call this command with `datetime` instead of 'id' in this new script?Should I use specific parameters as it is a `datetime` object?

Comment: I would try, without unique of course

Comment: It is working, much faster. Thanks!